# Save SQLite DB to a file?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android application that creates a SQLite DB and populates it with some data.

How do I save this database to a file so it can be shipped with another application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the SQLite database file from the DDMS percpective of Eclipse when the device is connected, it is stored with your application's files in /data/data/package_name/databases.

There is a guide on how to find and replace a database by a preset file:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Or you can just create an SQL command dump, and make it execute on first launch is initialized - however it will be realy time consuming.

Comment: Yeah I tried to used ddms but when I click data folder it's empty

Comment: Accessing a SQLite database file via DDMS won't work on non-rooted devices. Best to use a SQL dump

Answer (score 2):

sqlite saves its data directly to a file.  It's already done.  The filename is specified in your connection string.

Are you trying to export to a different file type for some other software to read in?

Comment: What I want is to have a pre populated db. So one app is run only once to read some data from a txt file and populate the db. Then I would put the db in assets folder of another app so it can read the data from there. So if it is saved to a file where is it saved so I can grab it a move somewhere else?

Comment: Take a look in the connection string where you connect to the sqlite database.  It should have something like "Data Source=" + filename. That's the filename of the database.  Just copy that file.

Comment: Where is the connection string? Sorry for stupid questions but I am new to android

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Android yet.  Someone over here is talking about connecting... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001124/how-to-connect-an-sqlite-database-sqlite-firefox-extension-to-android-applicat   It looks this is the part with the database name.  He's got it stored in a variable DB_NAME in his example.  public DbManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;

Answer (score 0):

To export your SQLite data to a file, use the `.dump` command. See [Exporting from SQLite to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163079/sqlite-export)