# Having trouble creating Android based application using eclipse for mySql connection

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse

I am a new bie on android and java platform. I am using eclipse IDE, Android SDK 2.2, JDK 6.0.2, mysql 6.54 and mySQL-Connector-java-5.1.7.bin.jar. When I am trying to connect to DB then I am getting error "com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationException: Communications link failure". Can you please guide me in this context. I would appreciate if any one can tell me the steps to connect. OR if I am using some wrong JDK or Connector in order to connect to mySql.

Thanks in advance.

-Krishna

Comment: You should probably update the title of your question to indicate that this is a database oriented problem and not just an Android problem. In fact, it looks like it is not related to Android or Eclipse in any particular way.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Android does not implement JDBC, so your mySQL JDBC driver will most likely not work.  If you want your app to communicate with a remote database, you'll need to provide some sort of web service for your app to communicate with instead.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc) question for more about Android + JDBC.

Comment: I insstalled sqlite3 in command prompt while creating database it will not creating and i added that path in environment variable so please can you help me how to create databasse.          Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i create WebService for Android Application using Eclipse, Please let me know the steps.Thanks in advance