# Connecting Android with Oracle server

Tags: android, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect android application to oracle12c sql server through jdbc. Android don't find oracle.securitypki and javax.management class files while loading jdbc. And I also checked that these class files don't exist in jdbc driver.

Please can anyone help me how can I make connection possible using jdbc.  And I also  want to mention that I have included internet permission in android manifest file.

Here is code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView text;  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
       text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_2);         
       Connection conn=null;
       String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.16:1521:MyDatabase";
       String username="system";
       String password="xxxxx";
       String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; 
       try
       {
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();     
           conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);       
           Statement statement=conn.createStatement();      
           ResultSet resultset=statement.executeQuery("select * from student");     
           resultset.next();
           text.setText("Hello "+resultset.getString(1));       
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           text.setText("Exception: "+ex.getCause());
       }
    }
 }
```

Exceptions:
Colud not find class oracle.security.pki.OraclePkiProvider.
could not find class javax.management.MBeanServer.

Comment: Share Code wht you had tried ??

Comment: Now, u can see my code

Comment: Post the stack trace?

Comment: I cannot add image of locat, so i have mentioned exceptions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015592/connecting-to-oracle-in-android

Comment: did u give me this link to try that code? @koutuk

Comment: no in that link there is offical post of oracle team member he explian how to use drivers properly .. they called it Mobile Server

Comment: ok thanks ,I will try and if not get it then I will again ask for help.

Comment: Can anyone tell me that from where  i can get javax.management.MBeanserver.class file?