# How to connect oracle in a android project

Tags: android, oracle, android-emulator, android-manifest

im developing a app in android 2.3, i need to connect to oracle server to fetch data for my app, can anyone tell me wat are the lib files to add and where. Please help

Comment: Really, I don't know... but, your application is for general public and you want to connect multiple mobiles to your database? I think applications must connect across any type of webservice, not right to the database server, but it's only my opinion. Good luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991334/connecting-the-oracle-in-android-application

JDBC

Comment: we are not trying to connect multiple mobiles, but we are trying to save information from mutiple users(app users) in our database(ORACLE DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution you should consider is mobile server, a product from Oracle designed specifically for syncing data between Oracle DB and mobile devices.

It includes a fully configurable synchronization engine that can either run stand alone, or be controlled from inside your app via APIs. It supports SSL so you can have safe, secure access to your data from Android and other mobile devices.

You can read about it here:

http://bit.ly/fmiAre

Also you can download it from the download tab on the same link and try it out yourself.

Good luck with your project,

Eric, Oracle PM

Answer (score 3):

Please be sensible. Write a Web service front end for your database, one that protects your database server from rogue activity. Then, use that Web service for your mobile apps.

Comment: The the Apex Listener for simple web-service access to oracle http://krisrice.blogspot.com/2010/10/restjson-access-to-your-data-in-2.html