# Problem with jdbc in android - unable to connect to database

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am new to jdbc and android. So pardon me if the question seems silly. 

I am trying to connect to a MySql database from an app. 

I went through the jdbc tutorial and wrote the following code:

```
 public static void connectToServer () 

    { 

        Connection conn = null; 

        try

        {

            //Connect to the database
            String userName = "********";
            String password = "********";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://my.domain.name/myDBname";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            Log.e(tag,"Database connection established");

            // Query the database
            Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
            String query = "INSERT INTO myTableName (A,B,C)" +
                            "VALUES ('a','b','c')");
            Log.e(tag,query);
            s.executeQuery (query);
            s.close ();            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(tag,"Database Connection Failed");
            Log.e(tag,e.getMessage());
        }        
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.close ();
                    Log.e(tag,"Database connection terminated");
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }
    }
```

My manifest code:

`<  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 
<  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`



The logcat is:

`....

Database connection terminated //my output 

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver // output from exception e.getMessage()`

**What am I doing wrong? 

Is there a difference between connecting from a java application and android app?** 

**EDIT :** Added manifest permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you are requesting internet permissions in your manifest.

EDIT: To do this, add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest.

Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc) link. Not sure if this can be done easily.

Also something else to look into is CouchDB. Its REST based, so you wouldn't have to build a php service around the MySQL DB - its purely REST.

Comment: Please check if the permissions I added are enough.

Comment: @Jack - fixed the blank manifest code, but the OP wants you to fix his problem (as opposed to him fixing it) :(

Comment: No it needs to be <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I added the permission and I am getting the exact same result. Database connection terminated.

Comment: Have you tested from a different environment, say your local computer with Java?

Comment: no. I have not. But I have not had any problems with the database when I accessed it using php. So there is no problem with the database.

Comment: Right - see the link I appended at the end of my post. It basically says "You cannot import a JAR implementing java.* classes easily. And, JDBC would need to be ported to Android, since it probably relies upon classes in JavaSE that Android lacks."

Comment: Will check it out and let you know.

Comment: @Jack let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2068/discussion-between-brahadeesh-and-jack)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has worked for some. Make sure you use the JDBC connector mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar.  Google for it.

Comment: I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.17 inside the eclipse folder. Is that ok? If its the wrong location, where should I have it? Also I guess the jdbc drivers come with the jdk1.7.0 jre7 package. So do i need to have the driver separately too?

Comment: you added it as an external jar?

Comment: No. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: alright well right click on your project folder...then select build path--> configure build path --> add external jar --> and then navigate to where the jar is on your computer and add it. So in your case navigate to the mysql-connector.jar

Comment: hi I am getting - Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not spend some time learning android.database.sqlite instead? IMHO, it'll be worth it in the long run.

Good luck.

Comment: I am trying to store it outside the phone so that anyone with credentials can access it. Thank you for the suggestion though.