# importing QName in Android

Tags: android, wsdl, qnames

I have used wsdl2java in order to convert a wsdl file into java files. The java files that are created are using class 
    javax.xml.namespace.QName

However, Android is not recognizing this class. Can anyone tell me how do I add support for javax.xml.namespace.* or javax.xml.namespace.QName in my application in android..

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc) questions discusses importing other java (non-android) libraries into android.

He basically says:

> "You cannot import a JAR implementing java.* classes easily. And, JDBC
>   would need to be ported to Android, since it probably relies upon
>   classes in JavaSE that Android lacks. And, you would need to write
>   your own JDBC driver for SQLite anyway, wrapping the API Android
>   already supplies, since I suspect the existing JDBC driver uses JNI.
>   And, when all of that is done, you will have an application that adds
>   a lot of bloat, making it less likely people will download and retain
>   your application."

Like he says you cannot do it EASILY, so it may be possible, just not easy.

Comment: While I know he is talking about JDBC, it still applies - unless I'm just way off.

Comment: There may be, http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/de3f70e52e1879d7 talks about compiling the result code/stubs ... but this is beyond anything I have done before.