# Android cannot connect directly with a Postgres database, and cannot use JDBC connections

Tags: java, android, postgresql, jdbc

I have this problem that my Android app cannot connect directly with a Postgres databse and cannot use JDBC connections. I've browsed the web a bit and some people say, that the best way to deal with this is to run a web service. I'm absolutely lost on how to tackle this problem. Should I build an extension of some sort or... ? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Android can connect `PostgreSQL` using `JDBC`, please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903481/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-postgresql-driver-android/21812893#21812893

Comment: A huge reason you should NEVER have a direct database connection inside your Android application is that your database credentials will not be secure. If you want to make database requests, you should use the approach of a web-server that securely talks to the database and returns the desired result to your application.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use JDBC with pgJDBC on newer Android versions, but not a good idea.

See [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/398670) and [Driver JDBC PostgreSQL with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10435609/398670) for why.

Basically, if you're on a device with potentially flakey connectivity, you don't want a persistent connection if you can use stateless HTTP requests instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can never have a direct access to a database which is on a server.
For this you need to run some server side code and use JSON to interact your app with server

This tutorial might be of help to you:[Connect android with PHP Mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

And instead of connecting to MYSQL you can connect to PostgreSQL with the help of these docs:

[PHP with PostgreSQL](https://www.php.net/pg_connect)