# error connecting to heroku postgresql database from android app. No suitable driver SQLexception occur

Tags: java, android, postgresql, heroku, server

I have an android app and trying to connect to my database created in heroku. I keep getting an exception though. I get the sqlexception: no suitable drivers.
Here is my code:
This is the class where I execute the sql statements and try to make a connection.

```
public class DB_Connection
{
public static final String DATABASE_URL  =
"postgres://iiuoxigyfsvsnd:aI8qkTno1bXZYtB74VovkMo75o@ec2-23-23-22550.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfpa4aagbgfcd7";
public int value;
// the empty constructor. without this we cant call DB_Connection.getConnection() from another class.
DB_Connection()
{
    value = 0;
}

/*
This is the method that opens the actual connection mto the Heroku Server
*/
protected static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException
{

    URI dbUri = new URI(DATABASE_URL);

    String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
    String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];

    String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + dbUri.getPath();
    System.err.println(dbUrl);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", username);
    props.setProperty("password", password);
    props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
    props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, props);
}


public void userLogin(Connection cnct, String userE_Mail, String userPass)
{
    String results = new String();
    try
    {
        Statement stmt = cnct.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE e_mail =" + userE_Mail + ";");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            results = rs.getNString("pass");
        }

        if (userPass == results)
        {
            value = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            results = "Invalid login. Please try again";
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqe)
    {
        System.out.println(sqe.getMessage());
        results = sqe.getMessage();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cnct != null)
        {
            try
            {
                cnct.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

/*
    TODO:
   password retrieval?
 */

```
public ArrayList getEvents(Connection cnct)
{
    ArrayList<DB_Event> eventList = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        Statement stmt = cnct.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM events");

        // every row returned by the databse is parsed into a DB_event
        // and added to an ArrayList<>.
        while (rs.next())
        {
            DB_Event event = new DB_Event(rs.getInt("event_id"),
                    rs.getNString("event_name"), rs.getDate("date_time"),
                    rs.getString("location"), rs.getNString("address"),
                    rs.getString("e-mail"));
            eventList.add(event);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqe)
    {
        //TODO
    }
    return eventList;
}
```

}

This is the class I actually try to use it in:

```
public class NewRegisterScreen extends ActionBarActivity
{
Connection cnct;
EditText number;
EditText password;
EditText fullName;
EditText email;
String firstName, lastName;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_screen);
    Button acceptButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.acceptUserButton);

    fullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPhone);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);

    // new DB_connection established. Added by Christina
    DB_Connection DBcnct = new DB_Connection();
    try
    {
        cnct = DB_Connection.getConnection();
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Didn't connect");

    }
    catch (SQLException sqe)
    {
        sqe.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Didn't connect. Not sure why");
    }
}
```

I keep hitting the sqlexception and when I click where it is on the printstacktrace, it says the error occurs in the class DB_Connection in the getConnection() method stating no suitable driver was return from that app. Can anyone please tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: It's generally best not to talk to a RDBMS directly from Android. Use a middleware layer over short-lived connections. It'll save you lots of frustration. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10435609/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/398670

Comment: What would be an example of a middleware layer using short-lived connections?