# Database in my Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on Android App that will user's input data (from text box) store in database and later will show that data and work with it. But I can't find any quality tutorial for this. Can anyone help me get started with databases in Android or just recommend good and extensive tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [simple approach](http://pastebin.com/3pfzXMgv) and test my sample [SQLite database project](http://www.mediafire.com/?569on9rvb4qoa7w).

---

If you want to insert value data from textbox then:

```
 final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
 String ee = et.getText().toString();
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('"+ee+"');");
```

Where **db** is an object of   SQLiteDatabase type and **et** is your textbox where user gives input.

Comment: @Croatia Boy let me know if it helped you.

Comment: your project helped me, you wrote it simple and clear. Can you tell me on which way can sqlitejdbc.jar help me?

Comment: When I have already completed database on my HDD and I want use it in my app, is SQLite JDBC good solution for that? And when I install app on my phone DB should be copied there so my app can use it.

Comment: If you want to use your manually created database(which will be in **sdcard**) just access it like `File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/Your_db_File.db" );  SQLiteDatabase  db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null); ` and use the **db** object as shown in my sample, you can also ship your database with your app by keeping it in **assets** folder and access it via code, [example here](http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2011/12/use-existing-sqlite-database-in-android.html)

Comment: And about **sqlite JDBC** : see [problem with JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc). If you still need it try [SQLDroid](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid/wiki/Quick-Start)

Answer (score 1):

here's google's introduction,

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

that section has links to two sample apps: [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) and [Searchable](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good tutorial series:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

Note that a database may be overkill for what you're looking for, you may just want to use Shared Preferences:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref