# Use sqlite database for iOS (robovm) with libgdx

Tags: ios, sqlite, libgdx, robovm

I have a **libgdx** project (Android) where I use a **sqlite database**.
I'm developing the same project in **iOS** version (robovm) and I can't find anything about sqlite or database for iOS version.

Is it possible to use the same sqlite database ?

Thanks.

Comment: The iOS way of doing this is to use the CoreData APIs which use Sqlite internally.

Comment: You can use Sqlite directly but it's not an Apple API, do you would need to go to their website http://www.sqlite.org and download the needed files.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but this worked for me

You dont have to do it EXACTLY like this of course, but this is how i did it

First i made a helper class for SQLite called.. SQLiteHelper
This would initialize things

```
package com.hamzahrmalik.mitto.sqlite;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import SQLite.JDBCDriver;

import com.hamzahrmalik.mitto.utils.Util;

public class SQLiteHelper {

    private String DATABASE_NAME;
    private JDBCDriver driv;
    private Connection connection;

    final String DB_PATH = new File(System.getenv("HOME"), "Library/")
            .getAbsolutePath();

    public SQLiteHelper(String DATABASE_NAME) {
        this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
        driv = new JDBCDriver();
        try {
            connection = driv.connect("sqlite:/" + DB_PATH + this.DATABASE_NAME, null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }

    public void execUpdate(String sql) {
        Util.log("Running SQL " + sql);
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            //connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet execQuery(String query) {
        Util.log("Running SQL query " + query);
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            return rs;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then each database extends this class
For example, i have a database of Messages

I make  a SQLiteMessages class which extends my Helper class i made

Then in the constructor i make the table

```
final String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + this.phonenum + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + KEY_MESSAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FROM + " TEXT," + KEY_TO + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER)";

        execUpdate(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
```

Then when i can add and delete and update as normal in SQL

```
public void addMessage(Message m) {
        final String ADD_MESSAGES = "INSERT into " + phonenum + " VALUES('"
                + m.getId() + "','" + m.getMessage() + "', '" + m.getSender()
                + "', '" + m.getRecipient() + "', '"
                + Util.formatDate(m.getTime()) + "', '" + m.getStatus()
                + "')";
        execUpdate(ADD_MESSAGES);
    }
```

Obviously you need to have a Message object but thats not really related to question

To retrive data simply:

```
public Message getMessage(int id) {
        ResultSet rs = execQuery("SELECT * FROM " + phonenum + " WHERE "
                + KEY_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id));
        try {
            if (rs.next()) {
                Message m = messageFromResult(rs);
                return m;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

public Message messageFromResult(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            return new Message(rs.getInt(KEY_ID), rs.getString(KEY_MESSAGE),
                    rs.getString(KEY_FROM), rs.getString(KEY_TO),
                    Util.parseDate(rs.getString(KEY_DATE)),
                    rs.getInt(KEY_STATUS));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

No external libraries are needed for this
Remember to add this to your robovm.xml

```
<forceLinkClasses>
    <pattern>SQLite.**</pattern>
</forceLinkClasses>
```

Comment: Did you ever post the complete code mate, I am new to LibGDX

Comment: Yes its above.. If you need help with something specific, just ask

Comment: Hey dude, trying to build this now.  What is this.phonenum.  Also could you paste your declaration for KEY_ID, etc and m.getId()

Comment: Hey dude, trying to build this now.  What is formatDate code?  I would love to see your Utils.  My messageFromResult wont compile either I think thats cause Message does not have a constructore.  What gradle imports do I need?  I get Error:(25, 20) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class JDBCDriver

Comment: @Burf2000 m.getID() is specific to my Message object which is what is stored in my database. Until.format date() simply gets a string from a Date object using SimpleDataFormat

Comment: I could not get mine to build due to it not finding the  JDBCDriver

Comment: @Burf2000 i believe it is a jar you need to download and add to your build

Comment: What was the jar called and where did you put it?  In each project

Comment: Dont' forget to add <pattern>SQLite.**</pattern> to robovm.xml 's forceLinkClasses

Answer (score 2):

There no docs (at least I am aware of) on how to use SQLite on RoboVM. Following links can be useful though:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robovm/5KF_nQJqHR8
2. [Does Android Support JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc)