# SQLite JDBC or SQLite JDBCDriver : LibGDX

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, libgdx

I am trying to get this working [Use sqlite database for iOS (robovm) with libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267005/use-sqlite-database-for-ios-robovm-with-libgdx)

The issue I have is if I Google SQL JDBCDriver (import SQLite.JDBCDriver;) it points me to https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc which does not contain the class JDBCDriver (taken from the sample in the stackoverflow post)

However searching around, I came across http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/ which does have a JDBCDriver class (WoopWoop)  However this requires you to put a sqlite_jni.dll in your Java project??  (and a .jar which just goes in the libs)

I am now massively confused, I been looking at this for days :(

Where am I going wrong here?  All I want to do is get LibGDX to have a database in iOS Android and Desktop, feels like something someone else would also want!

Comment: Choose one driver, and read its documentation. Don't just guess and gamble based on random google searches.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am just trying to find the driver that the code sample uses.  I asked the poster with no response

Comment: It looks like it uses the second one, and yes, that one requires you to use a DLL.

Comment: Thanks mate, any idea where you put a dll in a LIBGDX / Java project?