# Javafxports and SQLite on Android Device

Tags: java, android, sqlite, javafxports

i will write a sample code with sqlite, that must work both ANdroid and IOS (and Desktop)

Here is my **build.gradle**

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
    dependencies { classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6' }
}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases' }
}
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "1.0.0"
dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:3.1.12'

    //compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT'

    compile 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"

    //desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT'

    androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'

    iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
}
mainClassName = 'com.version17.Version17'
jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = ['com.version17.**.*', 'com.mysql.**.*', 'SQLite.**.*', 'com.gluonhq.**.*']
    }
}
```

**sqliteHelper.java**

```
public static void testSqli() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");

    String dbName = "mtt8.db";
    File dir = null;
    try {
        dir = PlatformFactory.getPlatform().getPrivateStorage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File db = new File (dir, dbName);
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:" + db.getAbsolutePath();




    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);

    //create table
    Statement st=null;

        st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS village;");
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE table village (id int, name varchar(20))");
        //insert row
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++){
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO village VALUES (" +i+ ", 'Erkan Kaplan')");
    }


    //select
    String query = "SELECT id, name from village";
    ResultSet rs = null;

            rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {
                int id = 0;
                id = rs.getInt(1);

                String name = null;

                    name = rs.getString(2);

                System.out.println("id:"+ id+ ", name: "+ name);
            st.executeUpdate("DELETE from village");
            rs.close();

    }

}
```

This work on Ipad Devices and Desktop but not on Android-Devices (like Samsung Tablet).

Can anybody please say me why this code above dont work on Samsung Tablets? or which depends i must add in my code?

thanks
Erkan Kaplan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the driver you need for each platform, and with Gluon [Charm-Down](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) find out about the platform and load it.

Using Gluon [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/tools/) on your IDE, in the `build.gradle` file it's easy to add different dependencies depending the platform.

**EDIT**

Added Desktop as well.

For Desktop we can use `org.sqlite.JDBC` and for Android we can use `org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver`. For iOS no dependency is required since `SQLite.JDBCDriver` it's already included by Robovm.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { 
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' 
    }
}

ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "1.0.0"

dependencies{
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"

    desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT'

    androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'

    iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
}
```

But we need to add it to the `forceLinkClasses` option:

```
jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'your.package.**.*', 'SQLite.**.*']
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Now, in your code you can load one driver or the other depending on the platform the app is running on, and create a connection, providing a local path like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649149/javafxports-and-sqlite-open-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted?lq=1):

```
private void testSqli() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if (JavaFXPlatform.isAndroid()) {
        Class.forName("org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver");
    } else if (JavaFXPlatform.isIOS()) {
        Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
    } else if (JavaFXPlatform.isDesktop()) {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    }

    File dir;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:";
    try {
        dir = PlatformFactory.getPlatform().getPrivateStorage();
        String dbName = "yourDatabase.db";
        File db = new File (dir, dbName);
        dbUrl = dbUrl + db.getAbsolutePath();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        ...
    } catch (IOException ex) { }
}
```

Now you should be able to run it on Desktop, Android and on iOS.
I've tested on the three of them, both with NetBeans and with IntelliJ, but the former manages the platform dependencies better than the latter.

Comment: hi jose,  thanks,  i edited my build-gradle above and get following error if i deploy on Android: http://pastebin.com/hzyWii1S

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ, maybe `androidRuntime` doesn't work (in NetBeans it does). Try to move it just to `runtime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'`. It will work fine as well on iOS, since it won't be added.

Comment: Jose,  may be, they have conflict?  if i comment or delete the line **compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT'** so i can **./gredlew androidinstall**  without any problem. But if i try to compiler some time result is always error like here http://pastebin.com/hzyWii1S

Comment: Why do you add org.xerial for?

Comment: as i say, i will write a small app. First connect to mysql-server on my Lan and save results as sqlite.db in clients ...The clients may be IOS or Android...

Comment: My build.gradle contains dependencies for android (sqldroid) and iOS (SQLite). Do you still need one for desktop?

Comment: Yes..some User can have Laptops and will ne use my app onlaptop

Comment: hi @José Pereda, do you have a solution for this Problem, that i can compiler all 3 sometime?

Comment: I've just edited the question to add desktop support as well.

Comment: jose, i test now with netbean 8.1 .... can you please say me where is REFESH-Button for Build Gradle under Netbeans 8.1? (under IntelliJ was right side above)

Comment: On Project tab (left), right click on your project root and select `Reload Project`

Comment: ok thanks...i have added now the missing librarys like charm, mysql, sqlite  etc...

Comment: Jose, i must comment 2 lines (see build.gradle above), when i want deploy for android.  Testet with Netbeans 8.1 ...Otherwiese i get always *GC overhead limit exceeded** error, can not be compiler..Ok it's not a big problem at the moment...

Comment: do you have tried with mysq compile lines? may be you will be get same error as i too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94924/discussion-between-jose-pereda-and-erkan-kaplan).