# SQLite JDBC driver on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to use **xerial sqlite-jdbc** to manage my database in Android with no success.I'm getting an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection` exception.I've imported this dependency `'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.18.0'` in my gradle.
My code is as follows,

```
 try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:hs.db");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException eString) {System.err.println("Could not init JDBC driver - driver not found");
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Using `android.database.sqlite` in my project is not option so please don't suggest that as an answer.

Comment: Official support for that library appears to be [in this Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/xerial?hl=en), based on [the documentation](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#public-discussion-forum).

Answer (score 4):

Gradle

```
 compile 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
```

JAVA

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver").newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to register SQLDroidDriver");
        }
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqldroid:" + "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/my-database.db";
        try {
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid

Comment: As i said that's not an option for this project.I have to use a JDBC  connection

Comment: Thanks.That is what i was using until recently.But after a recent upgrade of gradle and Android Studio i get this exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection".So i'm trying xerial now but i have the same problem.

Comment: that could be the xerial jdbc isnt installed, try clean the project if dont work try less this  line Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); because in the github repository haven´t this line https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Answer (score 4):

I needed to share some database code between my server DB and my phone DB, so I spent a lot of time writing the common code to use JDBC.

However, what I found out, after already being neck deep in this endeavor, is that **there essentially isn't a working JDBC implementation on Android**. I would **strongly** urge you not to go down this path - both Xerial and SQLDroid JDBC drivers have significant problems that I uncovered only during testing.

### Problems with Xerial

It just doesn't work on Android :) It doesn't even load - I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/248) and couldn't work around it even after trying for hours.

### Problems with SQLDroid

1. See the [Open Issues page](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid/issues) - some of them were pretty scary to me. The deal breaker for me was the lack of batch support.
2. See the [Known Issues page](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid/wiki/Known-issues) before you start.

Finally, I ended up creating an implementation of the small subset of the java.sql interfaces and methods that I needed, using the android.database.sqlite classes. This was far less painful than I imagined (it took me just a couple of hours, for the subset of the functionality I needed) and it works great!

Comment: Can you say more about "an implementation of the small subset of java.sql interfaces and methods that I needed" ? Did you use that same subset on the server? What API did you use to implement it? Is there a more direct sqlite API in java?

Comment: For each java.sql interface that I was using on the server, I created a class in my Android project. For instance, for the `java.sql.Connection` interface, I created the following class:
`public final class SQLiteConnection implements Connection`
I then in Android Studio, I choose the 'Implement methods' action to create dummy implementations of each of its methods. I then implemented only those methods that I actually used using `android.database.sqlite` classes. I hope this clarifies.

There are many SQLite JDBC implementations, but I couldn't find any (in 2019) that worked on Android.

Comment: In the page https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
it was wrote "Download sqlite-jdbc-(VERSION).jar from the download page (or by using Maven) then append this jar file into your classpath."
it was not correct to say "It just doesn't work on Android "

Answer (score 3):

Here's my way:

1. do some config in `app/build.gradle`, and copy a so file, looks ugly, but really works in my Android 9.0 system.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
}
```

2. then copy this file `sqlite-jdbc-3.34.0.jar!\org\sqlite\native\Linux\android-arm\libsqlitejdbc.so` to `app/libs/armeabi-v7a/`, which looks like this: [image].
3. and the built apk looks like:
   [image]
4. now you can enjoy `javax.sql.DataSource` of sqlite on android.

Comment: In my case I had to define following lines in the proguard rules file:
-keep class org.sqlite.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.sqlite.** { *; }

Comment: this should be most corect answer , since the instruction of xerial written: copy so in project path.

Answer (score 0):

update gradle plugin version and gradle version **to latest version**

File -> Project Structure

[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9hu2.png)