# dalvik.system.PathClassLoader JDBC SQLite

Tags: java, android, jar, sdk, dalvik

I`m noob in java. 
In android SDK I include JDBC SQLite library. 
When I try run app I have crash and dalvik error in logs

```
Process: com.example.aleksejs.myApp, PID: 3098 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.aleksejs.myApp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlitejdbc.so"
                                                                                            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                                            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.<clinit>(NativeDB.java:35)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:211)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
                                                                                            at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
                                                                                            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
                                                                                            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
                                                                                            at com.example.aleksejs.myApp.DB.openDbConnection(DB.java:35)
                                                                                            at com.example.aleksejs.myApp.DB.<init>(DB.java:20)
                                                                                            at com.example.aleksejs.myApp.activity.BachelorITFCourses1.onCreate(BachelorITFCourses1.java:42)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: From the stacktrace, it looks like it has problem linking the jdbc SQLite library 'ndor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlitejdbc.so" at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366) a'...I would check the installation again to ensure you got it installed correctly.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc