# DataNucleus support android with built-in sqlite or remote databases?

Tags: android, jpa, android-sqlite, datanucleus

Does DataNucleus support android with built-in sqlite or any remote database such as mysql?  EclipseLink does not support android yet.

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus JPA/JDO supports persistence to SQLite, certainly, as well as to all other mainstream RDBMS (and other databases besides).

DataNucleus has been used by some groups on Android with SQLite (SQLDroid), but I have never. Suggest that you read [this thread from their forum](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7274).

Comment: Thanks for info. It is not clear from that thread if android is officially supported. It seems that SQLDroid has been stopped developing since 2015. SQLite does not have its own JDBC driver?

Comment: SQLite has a JDBC driver but, like all JDBC drivers, contains native code that is not portable, hence there is SQLDroid for use on Android, or at least that is what a simple web search tells you ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728476/does-android-support-jdbc